# Protect spatial data with digital signature

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gml

I've been asked to provide a solution to protect spatial data (format .shp) with digital signature that are bundled together into a single file, much like signed PDF for example. I've been googling but can't seem to find an obvious solution.

My best guest is to export .shp file to XML (GML or KML) and then sign it, refering the idea from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature.

Is signing XML is the only obvious way to go for single file singing solution? if its true, can QGIS open a signed GML document?

Comment: Can you add some details as to what you are trying to prevent by signing the data.

Comment: My client's duty is to share the shapefiles to its stakeholders. While those stakeholders could change the data, they aren't allowed to say that the edited shapefiles comes from my client.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar challenge. Are there any recommended methods or tools available for adding digital signatures to shapefiles to enhance their security and protection?